# How to add using awk command in unix?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

I wantto sum the second column, but not able to sum it.

```
ls -al | awk 'BEGIN {FS="  "} ; {sum+=$2} END {print sum}'
```

but it showing the different result, which is not correct.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, it will be always good to mention your question clearly with all conditions you need.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Parsing `ls` isn't a good idea . Take alook at this. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0):

Your command is correct, just use FS=" " (**single space** not double space ,which you are using in command)

`ls -al | awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "} ; {sum+=$2} END {print sum}'`